# Set a Listener to Current Tab for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension that has different text and icons for when the user is on NON-Amazon websites and on Amazon.com.

Currently this is my code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(arrayOfTabs) {
    // since only one tab should be active and in the current window at once
    // the return variable should only have one entry
    url = arrayOfTabs[0].url;
    //alert(url);
    console.log(url);
    var hostname = extractHostname(url);
    //ACTIVE
    if (hostname.indexOf("amazon.com") >= 0){
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"img/color-ddg/logo32.png"});
        window.document.getElementById("headerLogo").src="img/color-ddg/logo48.png";
        window.document.getElementById("activeLogo").style.display = "initial"; 
        window.document.getElementById('activeState').innerHTML = "Active";
        window.document.getElementById("activeState").style.color = "#23BB61"; 
        window.document.getElementById('activeText').innerHTML = "Hey there! Because you’re on Amazon.com right now, this extension is sending your anonymous Amazon browsing information to Data Does Good to generate money for your favorite nonprofit. No personal or sensitive information is being sent - only things like the products that are being examined and products being searched for. You can disable this extension at any time by visiting your Chrome Extension settings. Look at you, you’re doing good and taking control of your data! Love you ❤️";
    }
    //INACTIVE
    else {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"img/gray-ddg/logo32.png"});
        window.document.getElementById("headerLogo").src="img/gray-ddg/logo48.png";
        window.document.getElementById("activeLogo").style.display = "none"; 
        window.document.getElementById('activeState').innerHTML = "Inactive";
        window.document.getElementById('activeText').innerHTML = "Hey there! Since you’re not currently on Amazon.com, this extension isn’t doing a single thing. If you go to Amazon.com, this extension will send your anonymous Amazon browsing information to Data Does Good to to generate money for your favorite nonprofit. Look at you, you’re doing good and taking control of your data! Love you ❤️";
    }
});
```

**I want the logo to be gray when I'm on a non-Amazon website;however, it only changes when I click on it first.**

I've tried to use https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated ; however, no luck with that.

How to create a listener to change it specifically by the current tab when the user switches tabs? So for example, when a user is on Amazon.com the logo will change colors as in

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"img/color-ddg/logo32.png"});
```

Edit: To make it a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example, here it my manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Data Does Good Amazon Affliate Program",
    "short_name": "DDG Amazon Affliate",
    "description": "This extension makes your Amazon purchases benefit charity through Data Does Good.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "homepage_url": "https://www.datadoesgood.com",
    "author": "Data Does Good, PBC",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "img/gray-ddg/logo32.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Data Does Good"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["ddg_amazon.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
          "js": ["contentscript.js"],
          "run_at": "document_end"
      }
  ],
    "icons": {
        "16": "img/color-ddg/logo16.png",
        "32": "img/color-ddg/logo32.png",
        "48": "img/color-ddg/logo48.png",
        "64": "img/color-ddg/logo64.png",
        "128": "img/color-ddg/logo128.png"
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab" ,"tabs", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "http://www.amazon.com/*", "https://www.amazon.com/*", "http://smile.amazon.com/*", "https://smile.amazon.com/*"]

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: What are you doing with the ``window.document.getElementById()` stuff? Is this running in a popup? Normally, you would [enable()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-enable)/[disable()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-disable) the `browserAction` when it's available, or not. Given that your extension is only active on amazon.com pages, a `pageAction` may be more appropriate.

Comment: If your issue is that you want to have the properties of the `browserAction` icon change (enable, disable, icon, title, etc.) based on the domain/URL, then these properties can and should be set on a per tab basis. Thus, you only need to set them when the URL/domain changes (i.e. let Chrome manage what it looks like when the user changes tabs to/from ones which you have already set). You then only have to watch for URL changes with either `webNavigation`, `tabs.onUpdated`, or port connection/disconnection from a content script (disconnect tells you when the URL changes away from amazon.com).

Comment: Got it, thanks @Makyen. I will include those for a MCV example. Yes, it is running in a popup.js which is include in my popup.html. The tabs.onUpdated only works on a background script. However, I need to change the popup window elements which can only be done in a popup.js. Does it not work in anything other than a background script?